# apt-get update problem

Tags: networking, apt, updates, phone, hot-spot

When i connect to my phone hotspot on my pc it connect normally and internet is ok but when i use the command sudo apt-get update doesn't work some errors appears, but when i use another phone it works normally:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease
Could not connect to packages.microsoft.com:80 (13.81.215.193), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download.
```

They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Open Software & Updates and uncheck this repository if you don't need it, or comment it out in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

Open Software & Updates and uncheck this repository if you don't need it, or comment it out in `/etc/apt/sources.list` by inserting a `#` character at the beginning of the line that contains http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease. You can uncomment the line that contains http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease if you have a working internet connection to this link.